# Tool for viewing windows file system with multiple panels

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, filesystems

I'm looking for a tool that will allow multiple panels to be visible while looking at the local file system, so that I can copy/move files easily between the panels.

I have been using 7-zip, since you can view 2 panels at once, but I feels as if there is something better out there.

What are the top recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

You can give [**Xplore2**](http://www.zabkat.com/x2lite.htm) a try.  The lite edition is free.  Here's a [product review](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2007/08/28/xplorer2-lite/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com) (also allows tabbed browsing - very cool)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I personally like [SpaceMonger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/).

It allows you to use it for 30 days before you have to buy it. It costs $24.95 and I think it works well. You can delete and copy inside of the GUI, although it does not replace Windows Explorer - I wasn't sure if you wanted it to do that.

I use this tool whenever I have a user that says "I am not sure why my hard drive is so full." Perfect for visually being able to see what the problem is. I have run it with Vista 64-bit so my assumption is it would work with Vista 32-bit as well.

[image]

Comment: Spacemonger free version has not been updated for long time. try freeware Space Sniffer instead. http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/) will replace Windows Explorer almost completely for file management - it's rad and can do multiple [single panes, dual panes, dual panes with dual trees](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/manual9/NetHelp/default.htm) and so on and can be customized almost to oblivion. It does awesome things like showing folder sizes and in-line bar graphs to easily see relative folder sizes when say looking through a phat share or whatnot. Highly recommended for serious use.

Answer (score 1):

I just open two or three Explorer windows.  Usually only one has the folders showing, the other one or two just shows the "other" folder I'm working with.